How to find the desktop which contains a Terminal window
I have a Terminal window on desktop 1 running some unit tests.
On desktop 2, I'm using Chrome on the Internet.
I want to run an applescript at the end of unit tests, in order to switch to desktop 1.
I haven't found a way to get the desktop which contains the Terminal window.

There isn't one.  You can try activating Terminal.app, which may fail to get you where you want if there are more than one terminal window.

Close all Terminal windows except for Terminal windows on desktop 1. At the end of unit tests, execute the following command.
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate'

The Mac should switch to desktop 1.

If you need Terminal windows on other desktops, then open some other application you don't need on deskop 1. For example, the Calculator application. The instead the previous command, use the following command.
osascript -e 'tell application "Calculator" to activate'


This works well. As all my Terminal windows are in desktop 1, I don't need to close any other Terminal windows.

Great answer! It's amazing that people are still finding so many useful things to do with these dead (?)/zombie-like languages: AppleScript, OSAscript & Automator. I say "dead" because Apple has relegated the documentation to the archives, and no longer maintain it. Apple seems to have abandoned so much potentially useful programming technology that's been replaced with... nothing AFAICT. I can't help but wonder...

I am assuming "desktop" in your question means "spaces" in apple terminology.
To get the spaceid containing a specific windowid, you can use the private function SLSCopySpacesForWindows from SkyLight. See CGSInternal.
For the windowid you can use some public CoreGraphics API to query it.
To switch to the space programmically, I don't know of a private function to switch space by spaceid, but you may be able to do that with enumerating all spaceid, then go to its index with apple script invoking shortcut keys.

Thank you for the answer, but I'm not familiar with Apple languages other than applescript.
